# How to see what gets updated on flush in doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

**EDIT** for those claiming "duplicate" question. Assume I don't know what entities I want to check. I want to check ALL CHANGES. Not "what was changed on entity x that I dont have a reference to.

Imagine I do this:

```
$e1 = $repo->find(1);
$e2 = $repo->find(2);
$e3 = $repo->find(3);

$e1->setMyName('xxx');
$e2->setMyName('yyy');
$e3->setMyName('zzz');
```

Then I forget about these changes, or forget to roll them back (not even sure how you would undo something like that).

Then at some distant place in the code, I call `flush()` and I wonder "why is my_name set to "zzz" at some record, don't recall doing so."

Is there a way to easily see what flush is actually doing?

Comment: If you need to see changes, you can get changeset for the entity,  `$uow = $em->getUnitOfWork(); $uow->computeChangeSets(); $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity)`

Comment: In such case I would check the symfony profiler. It has a doctrine tab which has all of it.

Comment: Create your own [logger](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html) using the *LoggerInterface* and log just before the flush.